# How to put permission or SSL connection in php? HTTPS PHP fopen/fwrite to CSV

Tags: php, csv, https, fopen, fwrite

I have an HTML form hosted on HTTP, and use PHP to open/write the data to existing CSV.

Now I need to transfer all these files and host it on HTTPS.

I'm not able to open/write to the CSV anymore.

Here's the simple code I use: (it all worked fine via HTTP but not on HTTPS)

```
$fp = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
if($fp) {
    fwrite($fp,$csvData."\n");
}
```

Please help... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing in your snippet suggests HTTP or SSL connection, just file writing. Make sure when loading SSL you're still in the same directory maybe? Shouldn't be an issue but some people configure their servers weird.

Comment: Turn on error logging and you'll likely find that the `fopen()` fails with a permissions issue.

Comment: How to put permission or SSL connection in php? my first attempt on server processing, I'm still a learning